# What syntax is used for expressions like QString%QString in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

When I was reading the source code of Qt5.15.2, regarding the implementation of the mkpath method in the QDir class, I didn't understand the following lines of code.

```
/*!
    Returns the path name of a file in the directory. Does \e not
    check if the file actually exists in the directory; but see
    exists(). If the QDir is relative the returned path name will also
    be relative. Redundant multiple separators or "." and ".."
    directories in \a fileName are not removed (see cleanPath()).

    \sa dirName(), absoluteFilePath(), isRelative(), canonicalPath()
*/
QString QDir::filePath(const QString &fileName) const
{
    if (treatAsAbsolute(fileName))
        return fileName;

    const QDirPrivate* d = d_ptr.constData();
    QString ret = d->dirEntry.filePath();
    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        return ret;

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    if (fileName.startsWith(QLatin1Char('/')) || fileName.startsWith(QLatin1Char('\\'))) {
        // Handle the "absolute except for drive" case (i.e. \blah not c:\blah):
        const int drive = drivePrefixLength(ret);
        return drive > 0 ? ret.leftRef(drive) % fileName : fileName;
    }
#endif // Q_OS_WIN

    if (ret.isEmpty() || ret.endsWith(QLatin1Char('/')))
        return ret % fileName;
    return ret % QLatin1Char('/') % fileName;
}
```

At the end of this method, the following two expressions appear

```
return ret % fileName;
return ret % QLatin1Char('/') % fileName;
```

These variables are of type QString and are connected by %. What is the syntax? I write this in my own code, which will cause compilation errors.

I wrote the following method in my own code for testing, but it will fail to compile

```
QString test()
{
    QString ret = "12";
    QString fileName = "34";
    return ret % fileName;
}
```

The compiled error message is as follows

```
Error C2676: Binary "%":"QString” does not define the operator or the conversion to the type that the pre-defined operator can receive
```